# Теряются значения в сессии на сервере - virtual memory limit

Tags: .net, asp.net, сессия, iis

**UPD 4, Проблема давно  решена**

Настроил режим sql, пока работает. Проблема была в хостинге.

---

Есть приложение на `.NET 4`. При тестировании локально на `ASP.NET Development Server` работает нормально. Но на сервере `IIS 7` работает некорректно. Еще детально не изучал, судя по исключениям, похоже, что теряются значения в сессии. Вот ссылка на [тарифный план](http://www.host.ru/prices/winhosting/basic.html) арендованного сервера.
`web.config`:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="20" />
```

Какие могут быть причины?

**UPD**
Добавил логирование в событиях `Global.asax`, появились некоторые прояснения.
Лог с сервера:

```
09.02.2012 12:16:52: Application_Start
09.02.2012 12:16:56: Session_Start kplhw03yoelo2qljz0k14idc
09.02.2012 12:17:47: Session_End kplhw03yoelo2qljz0k14idc
09.02.2012 12:17:47: Application_End
09.02.2012 12:18:05: Application_Start
09.02.2012 12:18:05: Session_Start kplhw03yoelo2qljz0k14idc
09.02.2012 12:18:05: Application_Error
09.02.2012 12:18:47: Application_End
09.02.2012 12:18:56: Application_Start
09.02.2012 12:18:56: Session_Start kplhw03yoelo2qljz0k14idc
09.02.2012 12:19:47: Session_End kplhw03yoelo2qljz0k14idc
09.02.2012 12:19:47: Application_End
09.02.2012 12:19:54: Application_Start
09.02.2012 12:19:54: Session_Start kplhw03yoelo2qljz0k14idc
09.02.2012 12:20:34: Application_Error
```

Проделав анологичные действия запустив отладку (или Ctrl+F5) на `Web Developer` получается лог:

```
09.02.2012 12:25:34: Application_Start
09.02.2012 12:25:34: Session_Start mw1xptnzueklab0rl0aft1nt
09.02.2012 12:27:35: Session_End mw1xptnzueklab0rl0aft1nt
09.02.2012 12:27:35: Application_End
```

Выводы:

1. `ASP.NET Development Server` работает так, как я и думал.
   `Application_Start` - вызываются только при старте приложения,
   `Session_Start` - в начале новой сессии,
   `Application_End` - вызывается только при остановке сервера,
   `Session_End` - когда истекает срок действия сессии или при завершении приложения.
2. `IIS` работает несколько иначе.
   `Application_End` вызывается при отсутствии запросов с клиента в течении очень короткого времени, и это влечет `Session_End`. Получается *приложение каждый раз запускается и останавливается*. От того и наверное потери данных в сессиях, раз они тоже каждый раз запусаются и останавливаются. Новые сесси, при этом, имеют прежний 'SessionID`.
   Причем, что естественно, если быстро-быстро работать в приложении, никаких потерь данных и ошибок не возникает.

От чего бы такое поведение приложения на сервере?
Это что нужно настраивать, сервер или приложение?

**UPD 2**
Установил `Visual Studio 2010 SP1`, там в свойствах проекта можно указать в качестве сервера `IIS`. Запустил свой проект на `IIS` в студии, приложение работает нормально. Значит дело в арендованном сервере.
На сервере по прежнему, после простоя около 1 минуты, приложение останавливается. Подключился к при помощи [IIS 7 Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=2299), что нужно смотреть?

**UPD 3**
Тех. поддержка хостинга сообщила следующее, цитата:

> Было обнаружено следующее сообщение:
>
> A worker process with process id of
>   '3872' serving application pool
>   '' has requested a recycle
>   because it reached its virtual memory
>   limit.
>
> Сообщение полностью описывает
>   произошедшую ситуацию - ваше
>   приложение само запросило перезапуск
>   через некоторое время.

т.е. приложение завершается, потому, что исчерпала доступную память?
Странно, по моим оценкам, для моих данных (чисто для данных) 1 Кб хватает вполне. В [тарифном плане](http://www.host.ru/prices/winhosting/basic.html) напсано "подходит для размещения *крупных* динамических сайтов"... "выделенный пул".

Утечку памяти думаю можно исключить, т.к. если просто открыть сайт на броузере и ничего не делать (что бы возможная утечка не заполняла память), приложение все равно через ~50 сек. завершается.

- Развертываем простым копированием
  содержимого папки проекта на сервер,
  не компилируя, может в этом проблема?
- Как можно измерить занимаемую память?

*Настройки сервера:*
Версия .NET: 4.0
Режим работы Application Pool: `Classic` (при `Integrated` приложение при каждом запросе запускается и сразу завершается)
*web.config* приложения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <!--
        <add name="ApplicationServices" 
            connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        -->
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Server=(local);Database=myBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
        <machineKey validationKey="8DDA935ED68BF24BF942BFF89AEC8FAD665DD32B58963DB274F3316D0A952CEC2231EA96540B834256386C16A3CECE5693953E76C45B82D05EE93678588B57C3" decryptionKey="333F1FCD85796BBEEB6B1CFB87CB44683F9953AFD6D6C6B7" validation="SHA1" />
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <pages theme="THEME1">
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="MyControls" tagName="UserInfo" src="~/Controls/LoggedInUserInfo.ascx" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
            <properties>
                <add name="FirstName" />
                <add name="LastName" />
                <add name="MiddleName" />
                <add name="Company" />
                <add name="Position" />
                <add name="Country" />
                <add name="Region" />
                <add name="MobilePhone" />
                <add name="WorkPhone" />
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="false">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="20" /> 
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="PHPviaFastCGI" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\php\php-cgi.exe|-c c:\php\php.ini -d sendmail_from=1874247@undeliverable.zenon.net" resourceType="Either" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMyService" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMyService" />                     
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>  
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    </system.serviceModel>  

</configuration>
```

**UPD 3**
Попробовал развернуть на сервер простейшее приложение, которое требует минимум ресурсов, проект веб-узла по стандартному шаблону в `Visual Studio 2010 Express`, ничего не добавлял. Результаты те же. Переписка с тех. поддержкой хостинга привели к результату, что они порекомендовали использовать

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer">
```

у нас был `InProc`. Про то, почему приложение завершается, пока умалчивают.
Пока будем использовать `SQLServer`, на производительность интересно как влияет?

Comment: Для начала попробуйте протестировать на локальном ИИСе. Дев-сервер - это хорошо, но тестить стоит в реальных условиях.

Comment: Что скажете об остановке `IIS`'ом приложения после очень короткого простоя?

Comment: С сессиями все в порядке, а вот почему происходит апп_енд не понятно и ето может быть по разным причинам, если например в приложении происходит необработанное исключение, изменяется веб-конфиг, что то с пулом приложения, кто-то ресетит ИИС и тд. ДЕВ-СЕРВЕР НЕ ГОДИТСЯ ДЛЯ РЕАЛЬНЫХ ТЕСТОВ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЙ!!! НЕ ЖДИТЕ ТАКОГО ЖЕ ПОВЕДЕНИЯ ОТ ИИСа.

Comment: Вы проверили на локальном ИИСе? Как оно рабоатет локально?

Comment: Отходил на не намного. Установил `IIS 7.5 Express`, нигде ее не вижу, не пойму как настраивать. Не удается интегрировать с `Web Developer Express`. Не подскажете с чего начать?

Comment: Интегрировать с дев-сервером ничего не нужно. Вам нужно всего лишь настроить в вашем солюшенсе веб-проект на запуск на ИИСе. Для етого пр. кн. мыши - свойства - Web - Use Local IIS server и вписать адрес, по которому находится сайт (по которому развернут он).

Comment: Поскольку вы установили ИИС после студии, то вам скорей всего еще приидется зарегить в ИИС фреймворк. Для етого нужно будет запустить из папки с фреймворком aspnet_regiis.exe с ключом -i или -r, точно не помню какой ключ - загуглите.

Comment: В `Web Developer Express` такого нет, есть только "Использовать веб-сервер по умолчанию" и "Использовать другой сервер", где есть только одно поле "Базовый URL-адрес".

Comment: Ну я так понимаю в базовый URL и нужно прописать локальный адрес к вашему веб-под-проекту

Comment: На ИИС должен быть предварительно настроен сайт или виртуал фолдер, который будет смотреть на исходники вашего веба

Comment: Ни где в `Web Developer` в настройках нету указания на `IIS`. Разные варианты пробовал и на чистую виртуальную машину все устанавливал. [Тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg594711.aspx) прочитал, что нужна версия **SP1**.

Comment: "Использовать другой сервер", где есть только одно поле "Базовый URL-адрес".

Вы сюда пробывали прописать адрес локального сервера?
Поставить полную версию студии возможности нет?

Comment: Пробовал, но, похоже я не правильно настраивал IIS. Для этого нужно, что бы IIS была правильно настроена и запущена. Только тогда будет работать с "Использовать другой сервер". Сейчас обновляюсь до SP1, там studio сама все делает.

Comment: Поставьте фулл версию студии.

Comment: Кстате, вам же совсем не обязательно запускать через ИИС проект в студии для теста! Хотя ето было бы удобно в любом случае для дебага и тд. Для теста сессии вам достаточно развернуть ваш проект на локальном ИИСе и потестить (вы вроде сказали, что ИИС у вас есть). Главное понять причину, почему приложение перезапускается, а после уже можно сделать выводы.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Использование механизма сессий для хранения временных данных](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424104/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Answer (score 1):

**[Не используйте сессию, если используете - не используйте InProc в продакшене](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424111/177221)**

---

Из комментов и из дописок к самому вопросу:

У топикастера был настроен режим хранения InProc (в памяти приложения), который вообще нельзя использовать в production + у хостера были жесткие настройки по ресайклу по превышению virtual memory limit. Приложение постоянно перезапускалось и теряло данные сессии.